# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos (\sin x) - \cos x}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos (\sin x) - \cos x}{x^4}$

The answer stated is $\displaystyle {1 \over 6}$.

---

What I've tried: 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos (\sin x) - \cos x}{x^4}$$

$$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos (\sin x) -1+1- \cos x}{x^4}$$

$$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1- \cos x}{x^4} - \frac {1-\cos (\sin x)}{x^4}$$

$$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{2 \sin^2(\frac {x}{2})}{x^4} - \frac {2 \sin^2(\frac {\sin x}{2})}{x^4}$$

$$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{\sin(\frac {x}{2})}{x} \right)^2. \left( \dfrac{1}{2x^2} \right) - \frac {2 \sin^2(\frac {\sin x}{2})}{x^4}$$

I'm not sure how I can evaluate the limit by proceeding this way. All help will be appreciated.

P.S. I'd prefer not using L'Hôpital's rule, it can get really messy.

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that I would prefer if the solution does not use taylor series approximations (or any approximations) for that matter.

Comment: The other alternative is to use limit developments.

Comment: L'hopital may be messy but it should get the work done, since you know that after 4 derivatives, x^4 will become a constant.

Comment: What's wrong with using L'Hôpital's rule? applying it twice may be enough to simplify this limit

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor series expansion?

Comment: Without using l'hopital i would try expand it using a taylor series, if you do this correctly youll get 1/6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating limit of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582275/calculating-limit-of-function). Or [$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^n}{\cos(\sin x) -\cos x}=l$ value of n such that l is non zero finite real number. Find l](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482773/lim-limits-x-to-0-fracxn-cos-sin-x-cos-x-l-value-of-n-such-that) (especially siméon's answer for a proof without l'hopital's rule)

Comment: @YuiToCheng thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I should mention that I'd prefer an answer without using taylor series expansions; but all 3 answers below use taylor series. I'm okay with it, but I was looking for a way that does not involve approximations/differenciation. I found a satisfactory solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/582287/557892).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 5):

By using trigonometry identity and Taylor series,\begin{align} &\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos (\sin x)-\cos(x)}{x^4}\\
&=-2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin \left( \frac{\sin x - x}2\right) \sin\left(\frac{\sin x + x}2 \right)}{x^4}\\
&= -2\lim_{x \to 0 }\frac{\sin \left( \frac{-x^3}{2(6)}\right)\sin \left( \frac{x+x}{2}\right)}{x^4}\\
&= -2 \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^3}{6(2)}\cdot x}{x^4}\\
&= \frac16\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Note that from the expansions $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)$ and $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O(x^6)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\cos(\sin(x))&=\cos\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)\right)\\\\
&=1-\frac12\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)\right)^2+\frac{1}{24}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)\right)^4+O(x^6)\\\\
&=1-\frac12x^2+\frac{5}{24} x^4+O(x^6)
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\frac{\cos(\sin(x))-\cos(x)}{x^4}=\frac16+O(x^2)$$

from which we find the coveted limit.

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$, $\frac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos x}{\sin x-x}\sim\cos^\prime x\sim -x$, while $\frac{\sin x-x}{x^4}\sim-\frac{1}{6x}$, so the limit is $\frac16$.